# Getting List data from Sharepoint 2013 using javascript

Tags: javascript, sharepoint

I got a sharepoint 2013 with some data in a list like below

Ex :

Name   | Employeetype|
-------|-------------|
John   | Permanent   |
David  | Temporary   |

Now i need to display this data in a html table using javascript.

I got some code , but i dont know how to use that code. 
below is the code i got so far

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.SPServices-0.5.6.min.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
  $().SPServices({
    operation: "GetListItems",
    webURL: "http://siteurl/Lists/test/AllItems.aspx",
    async: false,
    listName: "test",
    CAMLViewFields: "<ViewFields><FieldRef Name='Title' /></ViewFields>",
    completefunc: function (xData, Status) {
      $(xData.responseXML).SPFilterNode("z:row").each(function() {
        var liHtml = "<li>" + $(this).attr("ows_Title") + "</li>";
        alert(liHtml);
        $("#tasksUL").append(liHtml);
      });
    }
  });
});
```

Can anybody help on this.

Help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can Javascript client object model to perform basic tasks in sharepoint.

You can check the following link for more details:

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj163201(v=office.15).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj163201%28v=office.15%29.aspx)